# Why own head of Ganesh ji was not joined to make him alive instead of elephant's head?

Tags: ganesha

If joining elephants head, become alive, why his own head was not joined to alive? Also Shiva is a god, he can do whatever to make him alive.

Why need to behead other's head?

I got several questions regarding this in this site, but i can't get any answer. so i want to have my own question. Thanks.

Comment: Shiva chopped head of Daksha and put head of goat on it. But after long time when Daksha overcame of all his sins then Shiva converted his goat head into human head exact same as before. So it's not like that Shiva can't do. But Ganesha's case is different. He gave a boon to an Elephant and coz responsibility of maintenance of that boon he had no choice but to use Elephant head. And that elephant gave his head by his own wish. I can type all story as answer but I don't have site reference to link so my answer will just get downvote coz of lack of reference.

Comment: **why his own head was not joined to alive?** Because his own head was completely destroyed. Even mata Parvati tried to make him alive again since Ganesha was her creation. But She failed coz Shiva is Lord of destruction. No one has power to fix his(Shiva) destruction. If anything destroyed/killed with the hand of Shiva then it can't be fix/alive again by anyone but Shiva.

Comment: Possible duplicates of [Why didn't Lord Shiva realize that he was beheading his own son?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/14135/3500) and [Why didn't Lord Shiva put back the original head of Lord Ganesha?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7310/3500)

Comment: I got answer from the duplicate questions. but these questions not appear when searching same keywords, so i asked same question